# SQL Server mismatch row count in SELECT and UPDATE query with same conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

I am trying to match the update and select query count with same condition. but row count is coming with big difference.

**UPDATE Query:**

```
 UPDATE  MKP set MKP.Quantity =  MKP.Quantity + LQD.Quantity, ModifiedDate = GETDATE()
         FROM IM_MarketPlace MKP 
              INNER JOIN IM_ChannelListings CL ON MKP.ListingID = CL.ListingID 
              INNER JOIN @ListingQuantityData LQD ON LQD.ChanelListingID = RTRIM(LTRIM((CL.ChannelListingID)))  and LQD.SalesChannelID = CL.ChannelID
              Left outer join IM_ListingVariations LV on LV.ListingCode = RTRIM(LTRIM((LQD.VariationSKU))) and  MKP.ListingVariationID = LV.ID and CL.ListingID=LV.ListingID
         WHERE MKP.IsActive =1 and MKP.IsDeleted=0 and CL.IsActive =1 and CL.IsDeleted=0 
               AND (LQD.VariationSKU is null OR (LQD.VariationSKU = LV.ListingCode and lv.ID = MKP.ListingVariationID))
```

**Select Query**

```
select count(mkp.ListingID) FROM IM_MarketPlace MKP 
              INNER JOIN IM_ChannelListings CL ON MKP.ListingID = CL.ListingID 
              INNER JOIN @ListingQuantityData LQD ON LQD.ChanelListingID = RTRIM(LTRIM((CL.ChannelListingID)))  and LQD.SalesChannelID = CL.ChannelID
              Left outer join IM_ListingVariations LV on LV.ListingCode = RTRIM(LTRIM((LQD.VariationSKU))) and  MKP.ListingVariationID = LV.ID and CL.ListingID=LV.ListingID
         WHERE MKP.IsActive =1 and MKP.IsDeleted=0 and CL.IsActive =1 and CL.IsDeleted=0 
               AND (LQD.VariationSKU is null OR (LQD.VariationSKU = LV.ListingCode and lv.ID = MKP.ListingVariationID))
```

Please help me out for this.

and also please let me know how @@rowcount will work for update query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will happen if there is a one to many relationship between at least two of the tables involved in the joins.

The `SELECT` will count all rows including those multiplied out by the join. The `UPDATE` will just count the unique rows in `IM_MarketPlace` affected by the `UPDATE`.

Where there is a one to many relationship it is not deterministic which of the "many" rows joining to a specific row in `IM_MarketPlace` are used as the source in the update for that row.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to get unique rows in select query it gives less then what update query is doing.

Comment: so your try was presumably incorrect. But  you have provided no details about it