# T-SQL UPDATE statement affects less records than select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to update a `DateTime` column of one table with a date column from another table.

Before updating it, I am getting the records affected in order to see previously what records will be affected in the UPDATE. So I perform a SELECT statement with below WHERE clause:

**NOTE**:

- `DateTimeField` is of type `DateTime`
- `DateField` is of type `Date`

Code:

```
SELECT tblToUpdate.*    
FROM MyTable1 tblToUpdate 
INNER JOIN MyTable2 fromTbl on tblToUpdate.Id = fromTbl.Id    
WHERE    
    ISNULL(fromTbl.DateField, GETDATE()) >= DATEFROMPARTS(1753, 1, 1)
    AND ((fromTbl.DateField IS NOT NULL AND tblToUpdate.DateTimeField IS NULL)
         OR
         (fromTbl.DateField IS NULL AND tblToUpdate.DateTimeField IS NOT NULL)
         OR
         fromTbl.DateField <> CAST(tblToUpdate.DateTimeField AS DATE))

UPDATE tblToUpdate
SET tblToUpdate.DateTimeField = fromTbl.DateField
FROM MyTable1 tblToUpdate 
INNER JOIN MyTable2 fromTbl ON tblToUpdate.Id = fromTbl.Id
WHERE   
    ISNULL(fromTbl.DateField, GETDATE()) >= DATEFROMPARTS(1753, 1, 1) 
    AND (       
         (fromTbl.DateField IS NOT NULL AND tblToUpdate.DateTimeField IS NULL)
         OR
         (fromTbl.DateField IS NULL AND tblToUpdate.DateTimeField IS NOT NULL)
         OR
         fromTbl.DateField <> CAST(tblToUpdate.DateTimeField AS DATE)
        )
```

Note that I check `DateField` in `Where` clause to be in `DateTime` range before I update it.

The problem is that the number of records returned by the `SELECT` statement is not the same as the number of records affected returned by `UPDATE` statement.

The `UPDATE` statement affects fewer records than the `SELECT` statement returns.

Why is it happening if from and where clause are the same in both statements?

I think the number of records returned by `SELECT` and affected by `UPDATE` statements respectively should be the same.

Comment: Does your table has trigger ?

Comment: My guess is that you have multiple rows in MyTable2 for at least one row in MyTable1. It will only update the table once for each row that is found using a join like this.

Comment: Probably a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/56490274/73226

Comment: @Pரதீப் No, tables do not have triggers.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, I have checked in depth and you are right. The relation was one to many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy to demonstrate. When there are multiple rows meeting the join predicates you will get differing row counts from a select and an update.

```
create table Header(HeadID int identity, Name varchar(50))
insert Header select 'test'

create table Details(DetailsID int identity, HeadID int, Name varchar(50))
insert Details values(1, 'asdf'),(1,'qwer')

select * --this returns 2 rows
from Header h
join Details d on d.HeadID = h.HeadID

update h --only 1 row affected
set Name = 'what?'
from Header h
join Details d on d.HeadID = h.HeadID
```

Comment: Yes, this is just what was happening. Also suggested by SeanLange. Thanks for the great example so point for you!